# Autofill fields based on dropdown with append functions

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, mysql

I have this row with text fields that has id and it can append another row with my add button. And When appending a new row, the appended fields are automatically generating unique id. In the first column i have a  option that displays value from my database table products and when they pick a value from it, This will populate the other fields in the current row.

My problem is, How to populate the fields on the current row they want to populate.

This is what i have done so far

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                                                <tr>
                          <?php $drp = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products"); ?>

                          <td>
                            <select id="1" name="productcode[]" placeholder="Product Code" class="form-control name_list" required  value="">
                              <?php $pc = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT productcode from products");
                              while ($get = mysqli_fetch_array($pc,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $get['productcode'] ?>"><?php echo $get['productcode'] ?></option>
                              <?php }
                              ?>
                          </select></td>

                            <td><input type="text" id="1" name="brand[]" placeholder="Brand" class="form-control name_list" required  value=""></td>
                                                        <td><input type="text" id="1" value="" name="productdescription[]" placeholder="Product Desc" class="form-control name_list" required></td>
                                                        <td><input type="number" id="1" name ="qty[]" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control name_list" required></td>
                            <td><input type="number" id="1" name ="cost[]" placeholder="Cost" class="form-control name_list" required></td>
                                                        <td><input type="number" id="1" name ="um[]" placeholder="UM" class="form-control name_list" required></td>
                                                        <td><input type="text" id="1" name="vendor[]" placeholder="Vendor" class="form-control name_list" required></td>
                                                        <td><button type="button"  name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">+</button></td>
                                                </tr>
                                        </table>
```

This is the script for append

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var i=1;
                $('#add').click(function(){
          <?php $drp = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products"); ?>
                        i++;
                        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'">' +

                                '<td><select id="'+i+'" name="productcode[]" placeholder="Product Code" onchange="getState(this.value)" class="form-control name_list" required  value=""><?php $pc = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT productcode from products");while ($get = mysqli_fetch_array($pc,MYSQLI_BOTH)) {?>  <option value="<?php echo $get['productcode'] ?>"><?php echo $get['productcode'] ?></option><?php }?> </select></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="brand[]" placeholder="Brand" class="form-control name_list" required id="'+i+'"></td>' +
                                '<td><input id="'+i+'" type="text" name="productdescription[]" placeholder="Product Desc" class="form-control name_list" required></td>' +
                                '<td><input id="'+i+'" type="number" name="qty[]" placeholder="Quantity" class="form-control name_list" required></td>' +
                '<td><input id="'+i+'" type="number" id="costs" name ="cost[]" placeholder="Cost" class="form-control name_list" required></td>' +
                '<td><input type="number" id="'+i+'" name ="um[]" placeholder="UM" class="form-control name_list" required></td>' +
                                '<td><input id="'+i+'" type="text" name="vendor[]" placeholder="Vendor" class="form-control name_list" required></td>' +
                                '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">-</button></td></tr>');
                });
});
```

Here is the UI
[image]

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use `php` code directly from your `JS`, that's not going to work. It also looks like you think that your are iterating over something inside the click handler, I say that because you are using `i` but I can't see why that code would be executing more than one time, there is no `each` call or `for` loop anywhere I can see.